# Google maps changing click behaviour when shift key down

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to have JS actions occur on a Google map click that differ when shift key is held down. The built-in click event doesn't give key modifiers, so you can't make decisions from that event.

But you can add a native DOM listener, and check there:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'click', function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        // do something with x, y e.g. use an overlay to find latLng
    } 
    else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

(Adapted from [Control key + click event on google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061900/control-key-click-event-on-google-map))

However, I still want the normal click event to fire, in the appropriate scenarios, e.g when clicking on a normal area of the map, but not on a marker.

```
    map.addListener( 'click', function(e) {
        // normal map click
    });
```

However, this click event fires BEFORE the native DOM event, so I can't see any way to make decisions in the native event but still keep the behavior of the standard click.

Am I missing something? Is there a way, for example, to make the DOM event fire before the built-in click event?

Comment: What do you want to do on the "normal" click that isn't working?  As far as I can tell all the map "built-in behaviors" continue working (unless you are doing something to stop them).  Perhaps you could provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your "issue".  BTW - I also see a consistent ordering, "google map" events first, the "google DOM" events.

Comment: The normal click is working as expected, but it happens even if I have the shift key down - which I don't want. Thanks for confirming you see the same order - that was the main part of my question I guess.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my question again, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's obvious, but I solved this by simply setting a global variable in the normal click event, and then in the DOM click event checking for that variable being set.

This way, if the circumstances are right for the normal click event to fire, then the variable is set and the click is acted on in the DOM event, if the shift key isn't down.

If the shift key is down, we do something else.

Either way we clear the variable.

```
var mapClickFired = false;

map.addListener( "click", function(e) {
    mapClickFired = true; // acted on in DOM listener below
});

// bind to DOM event as well, so we can find out if modifier keys are pressed
google.maps.event.addDomListener( document.getElementById("map"), "click", function(event) {
    // check modifiers
    if ( event.shiftKey ) {
        // do things for shift key down
    }
    else if ( mapClickFired ) {
        // do things for regular map click 
    }
    mapClickFired = false;
});
```

Of course, this does depend on the ordering of these two events being consistently as expected. Since it's not documented I'm a bit nervous I've created something fragile.

Answer (score 1):

For me I solved that with global key-event messages which I catch to a global variable.

```
var keydn = "";
function keyEventDn(event) {
    keydn = ""
    if (event.ctrlKey){keydn = "ctrlkey"};
    if (event.shiftKey) {keydn = "shiftkey"};
    if (event.altKey) {keydn = "altkey"};
}
```

This function can be initialized with:

```
<body onkeydown="keyEventDn(event)">
```

Then you can use the key-events there, whereever you need it. Don't forget to reset the variable back to keydn = ""; if you have used it or in some global events like map, clicked or map, moved.

If leave some room for further improvements :-). Good luck, Reinhard

Comment: Thanks, thats one way I looked into. Unfortunately it doesn't work in an IE control embedded in an app, for some reason, so I couldn't use it.

Comment: Mmmmh, I work with that with an embedded IE controll ("Shell.Explorer.2") in an AutoIt GUI on a local basic. Next I would check if you can catch keyEvents in your GUI. If yes and you have the html page under controll you can sent the "keyDn = ctrlkey" to your js variable. Good luck, Reinhard

Comment: Hi Reinhard, are you able to handle shift/ctrl etc keydowns in the embedded IE control? I could do it for non-special keys like letters and numbers, but not for shift and ctrl. Of course its hard to tell where these are being intercepted