# How to listen for modifier keys pressed in a click event on a deck.gl layer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, deck.gl

I would like to listen for shift-clicks on icons in a deck.gl `IconLayer`. An icon can have a selected state and with shift-clicking I want to be able to select multiple icons. I am using deck.gl in combination with Google Maps.

The `onClick` event of the `(Icon)Layer` returns `info` and `event`, with `event.srcEvent.wa` containing the `MouseEvent`. This has the `shiftKey` property but is always `false` regardless of the shift key being pressed or not.

```js
new IconLayer({
  onClick: (info, event) => {
    console.log(
      `Shift key was ${event.srcEvent.wa.shiftKey ? '' : 'not '}pressed`,
    );
  },
});
```

I expected the `shiftKey` property to reflect the state of the shift key being pressed or not. Although this `wa` property seems a bit weird and the whole `event` is actually not documented as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

From Pessimistress on GitHub (https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/issues/3147):

> event.srcEvent is the raw event generated by the Google Maps API (map.addListener('click', cb)). You may need to find out how Google Maps exposes the shift key state.

Google Maps doesn't seem to be very helpful in exposing modifier keys. I found this quirky solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47574211/11561793